# Origin of Killing-Attacker-A-with-Attacker-B's-Weapon?

Tags: action

My friend at work and I are action-shooter movie fans, going back to our childhoods in the 80s.  We have noted recently that in modern action movies, there is often a scene in which the hero -- under attack by multiple gun-wielding enemies -- will engage Attacker A with his hands, redirect Attacker A's bullets to kill Attacker B, then kill Attacker A either with the hero's hands or Attacker A's own gun.  (Often the same scene shows the hero using Attacker A's body as a human shield against Attacker B's bullets.)

Some enterprising screenwriter, actor, or director had to invent this action-movie staple.  Who gets the credit?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this was an old [Kung-Fu Theater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martial_arts_film#History) trope from way back.